# how we can understand from spectrum of laplacian matrix of a graph that this graph is regular or not .

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

how we can understand from spectrum of laplacian matrix of a graph that this graph is regular or not .

if we consider $0=\mu_1 \leq \mu_2 \leq ...\leq \mu_n$ as the eigenvalue of laplacian matrix ,we know that the number of spanning trees is $\kappa(G)=\frac{\mu_2\mu_3...\mu_n}{n}$.

I thought that if we have a k-regular graph ,we can obtain $\kappa(G)$ with other ways without using eigenvalues,and then we achieve a condition on eigenvalues,but I don't know if we have $\kappa(G) $ without using eigenvalues,and also I don't know this plan is right or wrong, can you give me hint and guidance about it?or any other approach to make it.thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ja, it is possible. Note that $\sum d_i$ is trace of Laplacian matrix where $d_i$ are degree of vertics. In other word, $\sum \mu_i=\sum d_i$. Now, we can compute trace $Q^2$ where $Q$ is Laplacian matrix. It is not had to see that $tr(Q^2)=\sum d_i^2+\sum d_i$.

Hence, It is enough that we check that the following equality $n\sum d_i^2=(\sum d_i)^2$.

Comment: @kpax your welcome. May be this paper helps you:Which graphs are determined by their spectrum? by Dam and Haemers.

Comment: thank you!,I think it is not bad to thank you in persian ,azatoon besiar mamnoonam!

Comment: khahesh mikonam che jaleb man fkr mikardam shoma Romanian hastid.

Comment: baraye manam jaleb bod,in avalin bare ke in etefagh baram miofte,va nokte jalebe digash ine ke man in term in darso ro ba doktor akbari daram!

Comment: momkene alan begid pas nabayad komak mikardam ama vagheitash javabetoon bara man ke tajrobam kame kheili amoozande bod!

Comment: No, problem. It is ok.